# How to keep loading screen for minimum time?

Tags: unity, scene2d

Making my first game and stuck at keeping the loading screen visible for some time. It shows for an instance and disappears. By using loadasync the previous scene runs in the background? Do i have to pause everything and then move to the next scene? Thank you! The code is as follows:

```
public void LoadNextLevel()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadAsyncronously());
}
IEnumerator LoadAsyncronously()
{
    int nextSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;
    loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
    AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(nextSceneIndex);
    float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / 0.9f);
    slide.value = progress;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(nextSceneIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync()` doesn't allow you to control the exact moment to load a scene, in case you wanted to do a "Load everything, but I tell you when to move to the next scene" thing. All it does is doing a non-blocking operation in the background, letting you know how long it's taking (via the progress value) but giving you no control on anything else.

Usually, best practices are all about to NOT willingly add time delay in a loading screen. Nobody wants to wait more time than needed, being the app a game, a companion app, anything. This is a common problem when creating splash screens as well: please, *do not* include a minimum waiting time, because all users want is to use the actual app/game, and not stare at the splash/loading screen more than needed.

Animations play nice when splash screens load information asynchronously (i.e. from a remote server), while in contrast loading screens do the same but in a different context: the user is already using the app, and is just waiting to play.

So, what if you want to exploit loading screens to display additional information, such as random game hints or even some useful game lore for the player to read, given that loading screens need to go away as soon as possible? I can think of two possible solutions, choose the one that works best for you.

## Idea 1: "Press [button] to continue"

- A script triggers the async load of the next game level AND shows up the loading screen
- The loading screen displays whatever you want in it, as well as a nice-looking loading bar
- As soon as the loading process is over, the next level is already there, BUT the game is paused: the loading screen is still visible, and pressing any button will hide the loading screen and resume the game

An example of such a solution is the loading screens in the first *F.E.A.R.* game instalment: choose a level, loading, press key, start play.

## Idea 2: smooth transition

- A script triggers the async load of the next game level AND shows up the loading screen
- The loading screen displays whatever you want in it, as well as a nice-looking loading bar
- As soon as the loading process is over, the next level is already there AND the game starts. But the loading screen gets hidden with a simple animation (say, a fade-out effect) giving you a pleasing feeling, opposed to an instant and brutal transition from loading screen to game

An example is the first *The Witcher* game instalment, where loading screens would fade away letting the actual game show up.

In case you were wondering "How can I carry over the loading screen object from a scene to the next?", here's the answer: [`Object.DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) lets you define an object that the engine will not destroy when a scene changes, letting you bring it with you to the next scene. Where it will be destroyed nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Probably I'll try and implement the 1st idea since the game is a simple 2D shooter and there isn't much to load. Or get rid of it. Also thank you for editing my question!

Comment: Extra bit: pausing a game is quite easy, if you put all the game logic in `FixedUpdate` (separated from input management) you can play around with [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) to control the in-game speed.